# node js and hbase

Tags: node.js, hbase

I am trying to connect to hbase via. nodejs hbase module.
I have used

- https://github.com/wdavidw/node-hbase

to download hbase module for nodejs and trying to run the below code in my nodejs script which uses express and handles the incoming request :- 
.......

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res,next){
     var read_stream = fs.createReadStream(req.files.upload_file.path, {encoding: 'base64'});
              read_stream.on("data", function(data){
               // process.stdout.write(data);
                dataload(data);
              });
              read_stream.on("error", function(err){
                console.error("An error occurred: %s", err)
              });
              read_stream.on("close", function(){
                console.log("File closed.")
            });


}

function dataload(data){
 var hbase = require('hbase');


 var tableobj=hbase({ host: "{my server ip}", port: "8080" }).getTable('my_table1');
               sys.debug(tableobj);


                tableobj.create("my_column_family", function(err, success){
                    if(err)
                    {
                        sys.debug("error1");
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        this.getRow('my_row')
                        .put('my_column_family:my_column', data, function(err, success){
                            if(err)
                            {
                            sys.debug("error");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            sys.debug("success");
                            }


                            });

                    }

                    });
}
```

Problem faced :- when i restart the server[i.e the server created by this script by again giving "node {script js file name}" on cygwin command prompt] , then the hbase table is re-created and all the rows previously inserted are removed.